# Javascript works on desktop but not on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, browser

```js
var flag = false;
document.addEventListener("scroll", function (event)
{
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("button-up")[0].style.display = "block"
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight && !flag)
    {
        flag = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.display = "block"
    }
    else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 600)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("button-up")[0].style.display = "none"
    }
})
```

This javascript works on desktop browsers IE,Firefox,Chrome,Opera. But not working on mobile.

**Edit:**
Mobile OS: Android
Browser: Samsung Internet

Comment: Which browser and OS on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is likely to be caused because of either lack of support for Javascript by the mobile browser you are using, or if it has been disabled manually. Check the settings of the browser to see if you can enable it.
You can also try on other major mobile browsers like Google Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that use test mobile with google by F12 and  find  source in js files and find the keyword you and use debugger in code , you will see how  code run